# Accept different kinds of ArrayList in function argument

Tags: generics, kotlin

I want a function which can accept ArrayList of different types and do some operation with it. For example, I would like to print all the elements of the array. I have tried this:

```
val numbers by lazy {ArrayList<Int>(0)}
val texts by lazy {ArrayList<String>(0)}

fun main() {
    numbers.add(1)
    numbers.add(2)
    numbers.add(3)
    texts.add("one")
    texts.add("two")
    texts.add("three")
    printAll(numbers)    //error here
    printAll(texts)      //error here
}

fun printAll(values: ArrayList<Any>){
    values.forEach{item ->
        println(item)
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Int> /* = java.util.ArrayList<Int> */ but kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Any> /* = java.util.ArrayList<Any> */ was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String> /* = java.util.ArrayList<String> */ but kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Any> /* = java.util.ArrayList<Any> */ was expected
```

This is a simplified version of what I want to do. In my actual implementation, the argument `values` is being received from a different callback function, and I need to do more complex things with the elements than just printing.

What should I try in the function argument? Thanks.

Comment: `fun printAll(values: ArrayList<*>)` or `fun printAll(values: ArrayList<out Any>)` You will not be able to add items to the list in your function, only read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Generic Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions). In your example simply change you function to:

```
fun <T> printAll(values: ArrayList<T>) {...}
```

and kotlin compiler will change T to any type, you will use. You should read about generics - it's very usefull in Object Oriented programming.

Now you can use your function exactly the same way as before, because compiler will determine type of T for you.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved with prefixing `Any` with `out` in the method signature.

```
fun printAll(values: ArrayList<out Any>){
    values.forEach{item ->
        println(item)
    }
}
```

Read more:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-generics-and-variance-vs-java/